# Creating a real time changing rectangle in d3.js with a bitcoin WebSocket

Tags: html, d3.js, websocket, bitcoin

I have access to a bitcoin websocket which is giving me the current market price for the bitcoin every minute. I want to make a single rectangle that changes dynamically to these values being currently passed into my bardata array.

Here is the code:

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<body>

    <script>
        var webSocket = new WebSocket('wss://socket.cbix.ca/index'); //creating a websocket connection to blockhain.info
        webSocket.onopen = function (event) {
            console.log('Websocket connection open');
        };

        var bardata = [];

        webSocket.onmessage = function (event) {
            var e = jQuery.parseJSON(event.data);
            console.log(e);
            var high = e.high;
            console.log(high);
            update();
            bardata.push(high);
            $('.message').prepend("<p>" + "The highest bitcoin value for this minute is: $" + high + "</p>");

        }



        var height = 730
            , width = 1080
            , barWidth = 50
            , barOffset = 5;

        var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([0, d3.max(bardata + 100)])
            .range([0, height])

        var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
            .attr('width', width)
            .attr('height', height)
            .style('background', '#C9D7D6')

        function update() {
            svg.selectAll('rect').data(bardata)
                .enter().append('rect')
                .style('fill', '#C61C6F')
                .attr('width', barWidth)
                .attr('height', function (d) {
                    return yScale(d);
                })
                .attr('x', function (d, i) {
                    return i * (barWidth + barOffset);
                })
                .attr('y', function (d) {
                    return height - yScale(d);
                }).transition()
                .attr('height', function (d) {
                    return yScale(d);
                })
                .attr('y', function (d) {
                    return height - yScale(d);
                })
                .delay(function (d, i) {
                    return i * 20;
                })
                .duration(1000)
                .ease('elastic')
        }
    </script>
    <div class="message">
    </div>


</body>

</html>
```

However when I run this code a new bar is created every time. I know this is due to the update function re drawing everything once the `.onmessage` function updates again. I was wondering if there was another way to go about this maybe using AJAX or something? Some help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're facing is that your `update` function has only an "enter" selection. In this situation, the expected behaviour is having only 1 non-changing bar (because the "enter" selection is empty from the second time on). But as you're pushing values to `barData`, the length of this `barData` array is increasing, and the bars you're seeing are the new "enter" selections.

So, the first change is using just the **last** value of `barData`, not the whole array.

The second change is writing a proper enter and update selections. This is how you should do. First, bind the data:

```
var rect = svg.selectAll("rect")
    .data([data]);
```

Then, create your "enter" selection:

```
rect.enter()
    .append("rect").attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 25)
    .attr("height", 50)
    .attr("width", d => scale(d))
    .attr("fill", "#C61C6F");
```

This "enter" selection will work only the first time you call `update`. From the second time on, you'll only change the existing bar:

```
rect.transition()
    .duration(200)
    .ease('elastic')
    .attr("width", d => scale(d));
```

Here is a demo:

```js
setInterval(() => {
    var data = ~~(Math.random() * 100)+1;
    update(data);
}, 2000);



var svg = d3.select("#svg")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 300)
    .attr("height", 100);

var text = d3.select("#text");

var scale = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, 300])
    .domain([0, 100]);

update(50);

function update(data) {

    var rect = svg.selectAll("rect")
        .data([data]);

    rect.enter()
        .append("rect").attr("x", 0)
        .attr("y", 25)
        .attr("height", 50)
        .attr("width", d => scale(d))
        .attr("fill", "#C61C6F");

    rect.transition().duration(500).ease('elastic').attr("width", d => scale(d));

    text.text("The highest bitcoin value for this minute is: $" + data)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="text"></div>
<div id="svg"></div>
```